# website (https://www.nike.com/login) is detecting selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to login to Nike.com using selenium but it says "We are unable to connect to our servers right now. Please try again later. Post Request Login Blocked".
I only get this error when I try to login using selenium. When I login manually it gives no error.
Currently I'm using this code,

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/login")
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/form/div[2]/input")
email.send_keys("Email Here")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/form/div[3]/input")
password.send_keys("Password Here")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/form/div[6]/input")
button.click()
```

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT # 01**

Issue is not with the code. Code is working fine. Issue is that Nike is detecting the bot and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nike site not allow to automate their websites by using tools that is reason you cant automate by selenium

Comment: But there must be a way to avoid detection of selenium.

Comment: I have used a bot which open nike and login to it using selenium.

Comment: I don't want to place any order or do some other stuff with bot. I just want to login to nike and that's it.

Comment: can i have user username pasword to check login ?

Comment: why are you using absolute xpath please use relative xpath

Comment: //input[@id='659984ea-8f0e-4bbb-8d79-a1a702d0884f']

use this xpath for password

Comment: I'm using full xpath because ID is not static it changes on every refresh.

Comment: Dont use full xpath that m4eans absolute xpath please use relative xpath 
you are using full xpath but its not best practice

Comment: Let's discuss on chat

Comment: How can you linked in chat on stackoverflow?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222363/discussion-between-abdul-haseeb-and-justin-lambert

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with selenium but try opening the site on your machine and doing what you need with "webbrowser" [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html). If this doesn't work tell me.

Comment: We can open any link with webbrowser but how to login using it ?

Comment: Maybe try doing it in a very raw fashion. Automate all the user input. Try it with Pynput here: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

Comment: but I think that will not be generic. If the size of display changes then code will break.

Answer (score 0):

To login in `nike.com` Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following locator strategy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/login")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"emailAddress"))).send_keys("Abdul Haseeb")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"password"))).send_keys("Abdul Haseeb")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@value='SIGN IN']"))).click()
```

**Browser snapshot.**

[image]

Comment: The code which you sent is working fine but again same issue, server error
"We are unable to connect to our servers right now. Please try again later."
It only appears when I tried to login using Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

your code ran fine on my machine (although I use Java + Selenium, but that doesn't matter I believe). Now coming to your question:

1. You should try deleting your cookies at first by using the snippet below in some
   @BeforeTest section of execution of a test case.

   driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
2. Next thing, you should update your chromedriver version just for a recheck.
3. Specifically put a wait before button click.

Comment: I know there is not issue with code but website is detecting the bot that's why it is saying login Blocked

Comment: Yes you are right at your part . But it should have detected in my case as well. Did you already try deleting cookies ??

Comment: Okay so you successfully logged in to Nike.com using above code ?

Comment: For python command is "driver.delete_all_cookies()" and I tried it but same error.

Comment: Yes @AbdulHaseeb I logged in (obviously couldn't because of the credentials), but code ran fine or i shud say no blockage from selenium's end as such.

Comment: You should try updating your browser driver version. And also browser version.

Comment: the issue is not related to the driver version or with the code. Issue is that Nike.com is detection selenium that's why it's restricting it to login through Selena.